# How to create typeclass instances of a promoted type?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have a data type that I promote via DataKinds in ghc 7.4.1 and a given typeclass that I want to use to do type specific operations.

```
data Type = TInt32 | TInt64 | TInt16
class TypeTraits a where
  ...
```

And then I try to create typeclass instances of the promoted types like so:

```
instance TypeTraits TInt32 where
  ...
```

I get errors of the following type:

```
Kind mis-match
The first argument of `TypeTraits' should have kind `*',
but `TInt32' has kind `Type'
In the instance declaration for `TypeTraits TInt32'
```

trying to fix this by specifying the kind of 'a':

```
class TypeTraits (a :: Type) where
  ...

Kind mis-match
Expected kind `ArgKind', but `a' has kind `Type'
In the type `a -> String'
In the class declaration for `TypeTraits'
```

Comment: What exactly could you put into the `...` area? `TInt32` is not an inhabited type, so it can't use `a` by itself in a value position. I'm guessing something like `crazyThing :: TypeTraits a => SomeTypeConstructor a`? I have a hard time imagining how something like this could be useful, though if I really stretch, I can imagine it being useful *somehow*. Maybe.

Comment: The idea was to have traits for each of the instance. So I'm not looking for the value, but merely a placeholder for specifying the typeclass and consequently the function that I want to choose there.
for example: `class TypeTraits (a :: Type) where type HType a      sizeOf :: Proxy a -> Int`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is in the body of the class; types that have a lifted kind don't have any values, so you can't have a function that takes one as a parameter. You'll have to use `Proxy a -> String` or similar.

By the way, if you turn on the `PolyKinds` extension then you should be able to omit the kind annotation entirely. (Actually, you might have to do this, to define your own `Proxy` type, since I think the one from Data.Proxy might be `* -> *`, whereas you need `Type -> *`. If you define `data Proxy p = Proxy` with `PolyKinds` on, then it'll be inferred as `AnyK -> *`.)

Comment: The Proxy datatype in the [paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/dimitris/fc-kind-poly.pdf) finally makes sense, thanks!